# data.table: How to fast stack(DT) operation, and return data.table instead of returned data.frame

Tags: r, data.table

`DT <- data.table(a = c(1, 3), b = c(5, 2))`

`DT1 <- stack(DT)`

```
> stack(DT1)
 values ind
1      1   a
2      3   a
3      5   b
4      2   b
```

Now, it is changed to data.frame. Sure, I can use `setDT(DT1)` to change it back to data.table,

```
> DT1
   values ind
1:      1   a
2:      3   a
3:      5   b
4:      2   b
```

I would like to now, is there other ways in data.table to perform `**stack**` operation (or something like `stack function` with more efficiency) and directly return data.table instead of data.frame?

Thank you.

Comment: melt() of data.table is more efficient than stack()

Comment: Yep, load `reshape2` and then call `melt(DT)` - see `?data.table::melt`

Comment: who can write download the answer and give some explanation for `id` and `measure` arguments, then I can accept the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `gather` from the package `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
DT <- data.table(a = c(1, 3), b = c(5, 2))
DT1 <- gather(DT, ind, values, a:b)
```

The second argument is the name of the new "key" variable, the third argument is the name of the new "value" variable, the last argument is the columns you want to gather (all in this case). Also,  `gather` automatically calls a faster version of `melt` for data.tables.

Comment: it seems the reuslt of DT1 is not the expected result. It doese not change DT. Can you re-check it. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to change DT, do `DT <- gather(DT, ind, values)`. Do a minimum amount of work when asking for help.

Comment: Thanks for your critics. Yes. It is my fault. But I wanto to anwser like this: `DT1 <- gather(DT, colnames, values, a:b)`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did not understand your previous comment. I'm using the development version of tidyr where the third argument is all the variables by default. I've just realized my initial answer did not work in the CRAN version of tidyr, so I corrected it as you say.